# sum up values in all pages in textbox in page footer + SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a textbox in page footer, which sums up all the values in column "Players". The expression used to display the Total only in last page of report is,

> =iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,SUM(reportitems("Players").Value),nothing)

This makes the visibility of textbox only on last page of report as expected. But the SUM, sums up only the values available in last page.

I want to SUM up the values from all pages and display only on last page.

How to achieve it?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your expression only sums the values on the last page. Your expression should be:

```
=SUM(reportitems("Players").Value)
```

and then set the Visibility-Hidden property's expression to:

```
=Globals!PageNumber <> Globals!TotalPages
```

Comment: Still it adds up to only the values of last page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scope of the sum argument:

```
=SUM(reportitems("Players").Value, "MyDatasetName")
```

Chris's suggestion to set the visibility on the textbox itself is generally nicer than changing the value of the text for most pages to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
**Use Table footer(or Group footer)** instead of Page footer. In the table footer you can access the data.

```
=SUM(Fields!Players.Value)
```

**Method 2**
Alternatively, you can also create **another textbox** and put it after your table or data elements and put the value expression as `=SUM(Fields!Players.Value, "YourDataSet")`

**Method 3**
Another method is to do either of the above two and then **hide those textboxes in body**. Refer to the value of above textbox in the footer.

=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,ReportItems("HiddenPlayerSum").Value,nothing)